# Memory address of vector of uint8_t

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have the following data in a class:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> mData;
```

One of the library functions I use (from SDL), expects a void* to a pixel buffer address. I tried writing the following class member function:

```
uint8_t* GetBuffer() const { return &mData[0]; }
```

but I am getting the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const value_type* {aka const unsigned char*}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]
```

I am confused why I am getting this error (the vector memory is allocated in a class), why is it trying to return a const address? What would be the best way to fix this, if I still want to avoid having to dynamically allocate memory please?

Comment: Aside: `mData.data()` is better style than `&mData[0]`.

Comment: I tried mData.data() earlier, but had the same issue.

Comment: @Jary316 Of course, because it is basically the same. But it is *better style*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `const` method's `this` pointer is `const`, and thus are it's members. `mData` is thus `const`.

Either return a `const uint8_t*` or make the method non-const:

```
uint8_t* GetBuffer() { return &mData[0]; }
const uint8_t* GetBuffer() const { return &mData[0]; }
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand! I completely missed that important detail, thanks!

Comment: @Jary316 If my answer resolved your issue, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is marked `const`, so returning a const address is the only thing that makes sense.

Removing `const` will fix the issue, as is adding `const` to the returned pointer. If this function really *should* be `const` but return a non-const pointer, then marking the vector as `mutable` is probably the right thing; a `const_cast` is probably safe too, but you might want to ask about the details of when that's truly safe before you use it. However, most of the time an issue like this comes up, you have problems with your design and should rework it somewhat.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now understanding my mistakes.